# How do I render out a single mono audio track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I have a single audio strip (its occupying a single channel of the 32 in the VSE)  that is mono (a voice recording done in audacity as a mono track). I imported it into blender. I want to render it out with a single video strip.....every-time I do it goes stereo.

All I see is the ability to "split channels" tracks into mono under mixdown options (just audio render).

Why do I have to split channels and lose data if its a mono track? Is blender just automatically duplicating the mono track 2x and making it a stereo? So I'm fine if I choose split channels as it'll just render the one mono track as I wanted? I don't wanna lose data is all I'm saying. If it was a stereo and I did this, I'd lose half the data technically unless I recombined the 2 mono tracks later right?

Comment: In the VSE properties - press N - under sound there is a mono option as well as a pan setting to send audio to one side, this might stop the duplicate output. Blender doesn't give many encoding options for audio, there is no option to make the output video have a mono audio track, so even if one is silent the video might still have two audio channels. The audio in the scene properties relates to [speaker objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/audio/speaker.html) in the 3d scene, I don't think this has any effect on the vse output.

Comment: says pan is just for playback. the mono option didn't do anything either, made sure it was selected for the audio strip then rendered just audio via 'mixdown'. maybe mono option only applies when you video+audio render (*edit: nope!). So no luck :/ I'll test splitting the tracks in mixdown options and see if its close to my original mono or not. No idea how you would render a video WITH mono volume using blender...since its mixdown only that has tracksplit option

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Scene Properies you can change the audio format https://developer.blender.org/F351924.

> Is blender just automatically duplicating the mono track 2x and making it a stereo?

Joerg Mueller answers this: https://developer.blender.org/T54418#492826